# Bootstrap table fixed header colspan not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, fixed-header-tables

I have a bootstrap table which has fixed header. It is working fine.

When I add `colspan` in table. Table gets collapsed.

Is there any other possibility to achieve both `fixed header` and table `colspan`

Thanks in Advance

**DEMO :** **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jeysinghanbu/L92hw4j9/1/)**

**CSS**

```
.table-fixed thead {
   width: 97%;
}
.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 230px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td,               .table-fixed th {
   display: block;
}
.table-fixed tbody td, .table-fixed thead > tr> th {
  float: left;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use colspan on cells maintaining the full width, you have to change the td class, to maintain the bootstrap's 12 column layout.

For example, you can replace this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="col-xs-2">1</td>
    <td class="col-xs-8">Mike Adams</td>
    <td class="col-xs-2">23</td>
</tr>
```

with this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="col-xs-2">1</td>
    <td colspan="2" class="col-xs-10">Mike Adams</td>
    <!--<td class="col-xs-2">23</td>-->
</tr>
```

So, the `<td class="col-xs-8">` mark-up becomes `<td colspan="2" class="col-xs-10">`, in order to maintain the 12 column layout.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mbph57fe/)